# How do I get upsell for variable product in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**Short version**: How do I get upsell for variable product in Woocommerce?

**Longer version**:
I need the product ids for upsells.
My old code contains depracated code:

```
$upsells = $product->get_upsells(); // $product is instace of WC_Product_Variable::
```

The call should be the following:

```
$upsells = $product->get_upsells_ids(); // $product is  WC_Product::
```

But a different class.

I tried to get the parent instance using `wc_get_product($product->get_parent_id())` - but fail.

So, given the instance of WC_Product_Variable how do I get to the parent method WC_Product::$product->get_upsells_ids() ??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get_upsells-ids()` method does not exist. Try [**`get_upsell_ids()`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-abstracts-abstract-wc-product.html#source-view.473).

The following code will show you all the upsell ids for the product you are currently visiting:

```
// quick test to check upsell ids 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'echo_upsell_ids' );
function echo_upsell_ids() {
    global $product;
    $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $upsell_ids = $product->get_upsell_ids();
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $upsell_ids, true ) . '</pre>';
}
```

I have tested the code and it works. The snippet goes into your child theme's functions.php file.

Comment: Thanks but ```get_upsells-ids()``` is a typo.

Comment: I thought about it but it is right to report it. If my answer solved your problem could you accept it? Thanks.

Comment: No. It does not. I have tried it. Still investigating... I shall update. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try the code I entered. If it does not return any IDs it would be useful for you to publish your entire code by updating the current question.